# Compiling a multiple cpp files Error undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++, makefile

I am currently learning how to use makefile and currently dividing my main.cpp to multiple files.

here is my current structure

```
├── makefile
└── src
    ├── Graphics
    │   ├── Graphics.cpp
    │   └── Graphics.h
    └── main.cpp
```

and my makefile

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c
LFLAGS = -Wall
OUTPUT = game

game : main.o Graphics.o
                $(CC) $(LFLAGS) main.o Graphics.o -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o $(OUTPUT)
main.o : src/main.cpp
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/main.cpp
Graphics.o : src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp
                $(CC) $(CFlAGS) src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp -lSDL2
```

Everytime I compile. I always get this Error. But I have my main declared. is it looking for a main inside my Graphics.cpp?

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Graphics.o] Error 1
```

Here is my main function

```
#include "Graphics/Graphics.h"

int main(int argc , const char * argv[]){
  Graphics graphics;
  while(true){
    //do things here later
  }
  return 0;
}
```

//Edit.

*Btw. is there also a way not to link sdl2 on Graphics.cpp, If remove -lSDL2. it would give me all that sdl2 function undefined*

Comment: How does your main function look like? Add a simplified code in your question please.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: It may be related to SDL. Don't they define their own entry point?

Comment: What's the command that produces the error?

Comment: that was I was thinking too. but the first version single main.cpp works.

Comment: By the way, `CC` is the C compiler. Normally you'd use `CXX` for C++. `-Wall` doesn't make sense as a linker option.

Comment: @NamelikmeSaiyotan Also why do you add `-lSDL2` when compiling `Graphics.cpp`?

Comment: Thanks guys. as @Filip and pointed out. it was a typo error on makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your makefile; `$(CFlAGS)` is not the same as `$(CFLAGS)`, meaning that `-c` is not passed as a command-line option to the compiler when trying to compile `src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp`.

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c
LFLAGS = -Wall
OUTPUT = game

game : main.o Graphics.o
                $(CC) $(LFLAGS) main.o Graphics.o -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o $(OUTPUT)
main.o : src/main.cpp
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/main.cpp
Graphics.o : src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp
                $(CC) $(CFlAGS) src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp -lSDL2
```

Variables in *makefiles* are case-sensitive, which means that even though you wanted to include the contents of `CFLAGS` you instead got the contents of an undeclared variable named `CFlAGS`.

---

> <sub>**Note**: Without `-c` you are telling `g++` to run the linker, and as such it will look for a function named `main` so that it can produce an executable; `graphics.cpp` does not contain such function, and the diagnostic you have presented is emitted.</sub>

> <sub>**Note**: After you have fixed the issue with `$(CFlAGS)` you will be able to remove `-lSDL2` from the relevant line.</sub>

Comment: oh. crap. thanks. no need for -lSDL2 in compiling Graphics.cpp also

Comment: BTW, for C++ use `CXX` & `CXXFLAGS` in your `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

In your error message it says:

```
make: *** [Graphics.o] Error 1
```

That means this error occurred while compiling `Graphics.o`, not while linking `game`.

Your command for compiling `Graphics.o` is

```
   $(CC) $(CFlAGS) src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp -lSDL2
```

`-lSDL2` doesn't make sense here: You want to compile an object file, so the linker is not involved. But you're getting linker errors - why?

Because to compile without linking, you need the `-c` option. This is part of your `CFLAGS` variable. But you're not using `CFLAGS`, you're using `CFlAGS` (lowercase `l`). So I bet the command that make is running looks like

```
g++  src/Graphics/Graphics.cpp -lSDL2
```

without `-c`.

Fix: remove `-lSDL2`, capitalize `L` in variable name.